# How can I start multiple integrated terminal panels with a click?

Tags: macros, installation, visual-studio-code, init

Within Visual Studio Code, I'd like to have the possibility to push a button or run a command that would create multiple terminal panels and run commands on them.

This is useful especially when dealing with code stored into frequently unmounted drives, where every time you mount it you have to start a few terminals and navigate to the proper directories.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Mac we can leverage the power of AppleScript to accomplish this.

Firstly, we need to add a keystroke for creating a new terminal instance:

`{ "key": "cmd+n",                 "command": "workbench.action.terminal.new",
                                      "when": "terminalFocus" }`

Secondly, we create an AppleScript, like the following:

`` tell application "Visual Studio Code" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    # Term 1
    keystroke "`" using control down
    keystroke "cd path/number/1"
    keystroke return
    # Term 2
    keystroke "n" using command down
    keystroke "cd path/number/2"
    keystroke return
    # Term 3
    keystroke "n" using command down
    keystroke "cd path/number/3"
    keystroke return
    # End
    keystroke "`" using control down
end tell ``

Lastly, we add a VSC Task with the command:

`osascript ./my_script.scpt`

And then just run the task.

I hope somebody will find this helpful.